# mysql [client] group or [mysqld] group?

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble to categorizing some options in [client] or [mysqld].

The [DOC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html) says

> [group]
>
> group is the name of the program or group for which you want to set options. After a group line, any option-setting lines apply to the named group until the end of the option file or another group line is given. Option group names are not case sensitive.

Now some options are obvious where to put like

```
bind-address
```

But for example for the

```
thread_concurrency
```

option if a script from php or java connects to mysql to apply some query, where should I put the thread_concurrency to make it for that application. In [mysqld] or [client]?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds we can't use some directives belong to [mysqld] group with [client]!

I just tried it and it failed. My misunderstanding was because of a site claiming to tune mysql and was using all directives for both groups!